# XML Parsing Mechanism with spring boot JAXB vs Staxs vs Hand Crafted parser

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb

We are building Microservices using spring boot, however we have part of our project will be responsible for connecting with ESB through MQ and our contract is XSDs.

Our design team have 3 options:

- Go for generation with JAXB "Generating POGO, building the marshaling and unmarshaling, and generating XML request and Response"
- Using Staxs as a XML parsing library "However we didn't have any stream of data to be parsed"
- Handcrafted Parser

Design team rejects JAXB as a solution for this concerns:

- Custom validation cannot be handled in JAXB with spring boot
- JAXB marshaling and unmarshaling will cause performance issue
- ESB returned response will not comply with UI "however our services is stateless and ESB responses must not serve UI or being tightly coupled"

So Please i need to know what is the best approach that we can follow, Dev team see's the handcrafted approach is very time consuming.

and accuracy of written model and classes will no be the most accurate for that case.

Thanks,

Hamed

Comment: *"Handcrafted Parser"* No, no, no. Java comes with 3 parsers, and they are fast, so don't write your own. And if you really don't like any of those parsers, there are also third-party parsers available, so don't start writing your own, which will very likely waste a lot of development time before you get it error-free.

Comment: the problem, they offer me staxs parser or doing it handcrafted, staxs was suitable for streams and manage in memory data streams which is not the case. and handcrafted to customize the validations, and any custom validations can be done using annotation on top of spring boot.

Comment: Did you every use stax?

Comment: Actually no. Could you please explain more please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any evidence from the design team for these claims?

1. You can patch many custom validations on top of jaxb. There might be some frameworks that don't work well together with jaxb, but a general "cannot be handled" requires some evidence or specifics.
2. Depends on the actual requests. Ask to see performed benchmarks.
3. I dont really see how the approach to xml parsing would change that.

Anyway, there are a lot of xml parsing options. Without specifics/requirements it is hard to specifiy "the best" for that case. The actual requirements are usually so low and all common libraries are so good, that it doesnt really matter.